# eclipse syntax highlighting to differentiate between normal and prefixed HTML/imported JSP tag libraries

Tags: html, eclipse, jsp, syntax-highlighting, jsp-tags

Is there anyway to highlight syntax in a JSP in Eclipse by tag library? Let's say we have something like this:

```
    <%@ taglib uri="/path/to/a" prefix="a"%>
    <%@ taglib uri="/path/to/b" prefix="b"%>
    <a:tag>
       <p>Some text</p>
       <b:anotherTag>
          <p>More text!</p>
       </b:anotherTag>
    </a:tag>
```

Each JSP tag has significantly more complexity to it, and I'm dealing with a large, existing codebase that has 1k+ line JSPs with multiple levels of nesting, I would like to be able to easily see the difference between the HTML tags that are potentially being output versus the various different tag libraries being utilized.

Default behavior in eclipse, eclipse web platform, and every other eclipse plugin editor I've found thus far is that all the tags are highlighted the same. I'm looking for something where, at a minimum, the standard, non-prefixed tags are highlighted in a different color than the prefixed tags. With this, I could easily see the HTML tags potentially coming out of the JSP.

In the example above (referencing SO's highlighting), it would be ideal to see the prefixed JSP tags, `<a:tag>` and `<b:tag>` in green, and the non-prefixed tags, `<p>` in the normal syntax highlight color (red).

Answer (score 0):

From the Web Tools Platform, as long as I set a different color for tag names on the JSP Syntax Coloring preference page, and actually have a taglib directive for the prefix, those custom tags color differently.

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot of these settings? I can't seem to find anything other than this: http://imgur.com/veL85ml

Comment: That's the one.  Here I picked an unfortunately similar color for JSP tag names as there was for attribute names: http://i.imgur.com/PcfLDqQ.png